# Performance of get a specific character of a string in Python 2.7

Tags: python, string, performance, python-2.7, character

Suppose I want to get a specific character of a string in Python 2.7, suppose

```py
a = 'abcdefg...' # a long string
print a[5]
```

Wondering when access any specific character of a string, for example, access the 5th element, wondering what is the performance, is it constant time O(1), or linear performance O(n) either according the 5 (the position of the character we are accessing), or linear performance O(n) to the whole string (len(a) in this example)?

Comment: I like the idea that it might be linear performance on the length of the string. Like, accessing the first character of a huge string takes forever because it has to preload it all, or it's stored in some garbled dictionary/linked list thing :) Python has done weirder things I suppose...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> long_string_1M ="".join(random.choice(string.printable) for _ in xrange(1000000))
>>> short_string = "hello"
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda:long_string_1M[50000])
0.1487280547441503
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda:short_string[4])
0.1368805315209798
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda:short_string[random.randint(0,4)])
1.7327393072888242
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda:long_string_1M[random.randint(50000,100000)])
1.779330312345877
```

looks like O(1) to me

they acheive it because a string is consecutive memory locations so indexing into it is simply a matter of offsetting ... there is no seek (at least that is my understanding)  if you know c/c++ its something like `*(pointer+offset)` (its been a long time since ive done C so that might be a little wrong)

Comment: Thanks Joran, vote up and I have the same feeling/result, and curious how it is implemented internally to have O(1) performance? Any detailed or high level idea is appreciated. :)

Comment: I assumed it because of the details at https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity ... although they do not callout string specifically it is close enough to a list ...

Comment: Nice reference Joran. Vote up, and will mark your reply as answer in 2 mins when SO allows me. You answered too fast. :)

Comment: I agree - anything in that table that talks about tuples can probably be applied to strings (didn't look that carefully, but probably). There are a bunch of places where the python docs draw analogy and the implementation is similar

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Joran's answer, I'd point you to [this reference implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Objects/stringobject.c), confirming his answer that it is O(1) lookup

```c
/* String slice a[i:j] consists of characters a[i] ... a[j-1] */        
static PyObject *    
string_slice(register PyStringObject *a, register Py_ssize_t i,    
             register Py_ssize_t j)    
     /* j -- may be negative! */    
{    
    if (i < 0)    
        i = 0;    
    if (j < 0)    
        j = 0; /* Avoid signed/unsigned bug in next line */    
    if (j > Py_SIZE(a))    
        j = Py_SIZE(a);    
    if (i == 0 && j == Py_SIZE(a) && PyString_CheckExact(a)) {    
        /* It's the same as a */    
        Py_INCREF(a);    
        return (PyObject *)a;    
    }    
    if (j < i)  
        j = i;    
    return PyString_FromStringAndSize(a->ob_sval + i, j-i);    
}
```

---

**Why this should be your intuition**

[Python strings are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097994/arent-python-strings-immutable). This common optimization allows tricks like assuming contiguous data when desirable. Note that under the hood, we sometimes just need to compute the offset from the memory location in C (obviously implementation specific)

[There are several places](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips) where the immutability of strings is something that can be relied on (or vexed by). In the python author's words;

> There are several advantages [to strings being immutable]. One is
> performance: knowing that a string is immutable means we can allocate
> space for it at creation time

So although we may not be able to guarantee, as far as I know, this behaviour across implementations, it's awfully safe to assume.

Comment: lol ... great minds think alike ... (see my edit) nice link to ref +1 from me

Comment: @Joran haha ya +1 on yours too , that edit came in as I was typing mine up. I was hoping you weren't going to throw in my link otherwise I would have to cancel the post

Comment: @IharBury thanks for the feedback on an old question :) Why is PyString_FromStringAndSize not O(1)? Looking at the same reference implementation, I don't see any "loops"; there is a malloc call, is that what you consider to be "not O(1)"? I don't usually consider those proportional to the size of the string at all in, which seems consistent with other SO answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282926/time-complexity-of-memory-allocation, https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/83834/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-memory-allocation-assumed-to-be

Comment: @IharBury hmm where does that happen *on the entire string*? It's true that it might copy the slice of the string, but the OP Is asking about accessing a single character, so that would be a memcpy on one element (and the reference has a specific case, it looks to me, to *not* memcpy for size-1 objects, but intern them (line 104). Note that j-1==1 for the OP's case, we're not calling PyString_FromStringAndSize on the entire initial object