# Big O of zfill in Python?

Tags: python, function

I have a question: what is the **big O** or time complexity of Python's built-in function **zfill**?
I don't know where to find this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python zfill implementation lives [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/63298930fb531ba2bb4f23bc3b915dbf1e17e9e1/Objects/stringlib/transmogrify.h#L222).

Here is is relatively apparent that the implementation is primarily composed of an allocation and memset/memcpy, with the rest being very simple addition/subtraction.

The big-O of these operations are platform/implementation/circumstance driven and often not that depended on the length of the string (They might happen instantaneous. They might allocate a new page for heap and request access to extra memory from an external services taking a few second). But for your purposes I would act like it is `O(n)`, where `n` is the size of the resulting string, since that is probably what `memset/memcpy` have (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282926/time-complexity-of-memory-allocation) alloc is not really measurable).

But in truth, you probably shouldn't worry about this, since there is nothing you can do to change it. A manually implementation would certainly be slower.